# how to ngfor in matColumnDef for dynamicly table?

Tags: angular, angular-material

i want table in dynamcally

```
<div *ngFor="let item of displayedColumns; let i=index">

            <ng-container   matColumnDef={{item}}>
                <th style="margin: 15px;" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>{{item}}</th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.item}} </td>
            </ng-container>

</div>
```

{{element.item}} is not read

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element[item]}} </td>
```